# Where do you place the “preseed.cfg” file?

Tags: windows-7, vagrant, packer

I’m trying to create a Ubuntu Vagrant box using [Packer](https://www.packer.io). I’m confused about where to place the `preseed.cfg` file. Does it have to be in directory mentioned in `http_directory`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of Chef's [Bento](https://github.com/chef/bento) repository which has files for all kinds of Vagrant bases. In their repo, they put the files in an /http directory. This isn't a hard and fast answer, but you might check out their scripts and see how they're pulling it off. Also, that's a gold mine if you like to do various kinds of system builds.